# Javascript Regular Expression to add dash after every 3rd and 4th characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

The following regex:

```
x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "-");
```

adds dash after each **3rd** character so entered `123456789` turns into `123-456-789`.
Im trying to use this regex to format phone number. The problem arises on the 10th character. So entered `1234567890` turns into `1-234-567-890`.

How would I modify the above regex to turn strings that have 10 digits into `123-456-7890`. I use this regex because this happens as user is typing in uses **keyup** event.

If you know easier or better way of doing this please help me out, dashes has to be added while user is typing in. No other characters allowed.

**Notes:**

1. Cant use Jquery Masked input plugin (because if editing the middle character it's focus gets messed up)

Comment: How long can the phone numbers be? 9 and 10 are what I see here, but is there any other possibility that you have to consider?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about

```
> "12345678".match(/\d{3}(?=\d{2,3})|\d+/g).join("-")
"123-456-78"
> "123456789".match(/\d{3}(?=\d{2,3})|\d+/g).join("-")
"123-456-789"
> "1234567890".match(/\d{3}(?=\d{2,3})|\d+/g).join("-")
"123-456-7890"
```

Comment: works but If i remove/add digit from middle and add digit it does not reformat it. Example: "123-456-7890" added number 1 next to 5 gives result: "123-4516-7890" should not allow

Comment: @GGio: remove the dashes first `val=val.replace(/-/g,'')` and then reformat.

Comment: 123-4567890, Pls help me to get a result like this. Only insert hyphen after the first n digit

Answer (score 4):

**If you ALREADY have the complete number or string**

```
var x = "329193914";
console.log(x.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
```

**If you WANT AS someone is typing...**

```
$('#locAcct').keyup(function () {
    var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
    if (foo.length > 0) {
        foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
    }
    $(this).val(foo);
});
```

Comment: how to format in 21-12-2022. in date format?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use regular expressions for everything or would maybe something like this also help you out?

```
function convertToValidPhoneNumber(text) {
    var result = [];
    text = text.replace(/[^\d]/g,"");
    while (text.length >= 6) {
        result.push(text.substring(0, 3));
        text = text.substring(3);
    }
    if(text.length > 0) result.push(text);
    return result.join("-");
}
```

You could use this function everytime the text in your inputfield changes. It will produce the following results:

```
"12345678" -> "123-45678"
"123d456789" -> "123-456-789"
"123-4567-89" -> "123-456-789"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way would be to add dash after every **`n digits`** would be like

```js
var a = $('#result');
var x = "<p>asiija kasdjflaksd jflka asdkhflakjshdfk jasd flaksjdhfklasd f</p><p>12345678912345678912345678912312344545545456789</p>"

a.html(x.replace(/(\d{15})/g, "$1-"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest way is the following using simple javascript onkey and function... it will put dash hyphen after every 3 characters you input / type.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="sector" id="sector" onkeyup="addDash(this)" required>
```

add the following script

```
<script>
    function addDash (element) {
        let ele = document.getElementById(element.id);
        ele = ele.value.split('-').join('');    // Remove dash (-) if mistakenly entered.

        let finalVal = ele.match(/.{1,3}/g).join('-');
        document.getElementById(element.id).value = finalVal;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you screaming on all your answers today? Please, edit your answer and use lowercase instead of UPPERCASE.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros it's just because of caps, btw why is it important to write in lowercase?

Comment: Because messages typed completely in capital letters are equated to shouting and other argumentative behaviours.