# Adding Dashes to a number without many lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number returned from the database

e.g.

```
329193914
```

What I would like to do it simply be able to just insert dashes every 3 characters.

e.g.

```
329-193-914
```

I was looking at regex, replace and slice ,  slice I had a hard time with as a lot of example are like  f.value  and i'm not passing in "this" (entire element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Regular Expression to add dash after every 3rd and 4th characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598470/javascript-regular-expression-to-add-dash-after-every-3rd-and-4th-characters)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5775Laky/ is how I would do it. To expand, you can use .match(/(\d{3})/g) to return an array of numbers split into threes. I just used an array to insert the dashes but I see an answer now which uses join, which is much neater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your number can be treated as a string:

```
var str = '329193914';
var arr = str.match(/.{3}/g); // => ['329', '193', '914']
var str2 = arr.join('-'); // => '329-193-914'
```